# Design of Rest API that can handle million of request

Tags: rest

Today i was asked in interview. How would i design a rest api that would handle millions of request. Do i need to do something special in designing a rest api. I thought if there would be something problems i would create threads. What could be the answer of this.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-ideal-architecture-for-an-API-that-will-need-to-handle-thousands-of-requests-per-a-second

Answer (score 1):

this answers should work as a response:

To handle 'millions of request' the system must be deployed on multiple web servers behind a load-balancer that would round robin between each.

if the system is hitting a datastore, a second level cache(ehcache, memcache,etc.) should be used to reduce load on the datastore.